# CheckAdd ApplyCheckToTxnAdd useMacro usage

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

According to the documentation the ApplyCheckToTxnAdd member of a CheckAdd message in the QuickBooks SDK takes an optional usemacro value. When I do this it errors with a There is a missing element: "TxnID".

This suggests to me that there is either a bug in the documentation or Web Connector or QuickBooks itself.

The business scenario I am trying to replicate is to paydown a customer credit memo by writing a check.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Mark

Comment: Post your code, the outgoing XML request, and the incoming XML response. No one is going to be able to help you unless you post some details about what you're doing.